# Retrieve add from azure mobile services

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, azure-mobile-services

I want to retrieve data from azure mobile service using this code:

```
//class
class country
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string country_name { get; set; }
    public int country_id { get; set; }
}
```

These are my global variables:

```
private MobileServiceCollection<country, country> items;
private IMobileServiceTable<country> todoTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<country>();

private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   items = await todoTable.Where(todoItem=>todoItem.country_name=="pakistan").ToCollectionAsync(;
   mygridview.ItemsSource  = items;
}
// mydridview is the name of  gridview.
mygridview.ItemsSource  = items;
```

But it only Show `azureapp.code.country` but not the data.

Note: azureapp is the name of application and country is the name of class and also the name of table in azure.

Comment: Hello User,

Just a little clarification, the country on the code here above are without any capital letter. This is a class you have right? Or do you also have some kind of an enum sharing the same name?

Comment: yes but in the above code, you wrote country, with no capital, is this a typo?

Comment: I updated my answer, sorry for the confusion, we usually use capital letters for classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code here above is good, it should actually works.

I think that actually you are displaying in your XAML view the object pointer and not a field. Could you please try to refer to an attribute of the class "Country" in your gridview code?

Comment: Otherwise please add your XAML code of the gridview

Comment: <GridView 
            x:Name="mygridview" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    Height="328" 
                    Margin="28,302,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="360"/>

Comment: THis is code for the grid,, sorry i am new. what should i edit in code.

Comment: No problem! Please change it to :
 
`<GridView x:Name="mygridview" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="328" Margin="28,302,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="360">  
<GridView.Header>
        <StackPanel Width="480" Margin="0,4,14,0">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding country_name}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding country_id}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </GridView.Header>
</GridView>`

This should allow your items to be displayed correctly in the header section.

Comment: still shwing the same result "azureapp.Code.country" but not data.

Comment: if i change the query to this, then it show "azureapp.Code.country" three times, as there are three rows in table.

 items = await todoTable.ToCollectionAsync();
    mygridview.ItemsSource  = items;

Comment: Yup, but you only have a single one with Pakistan, right? Your query is totally working, the problems lies actually with the XAML and how you are displaying the object.

Comment: try to do this as XAML...
`<GridView x:Name="mygridview" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="328" Margin="28,302,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="360">  <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="20">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding country_id}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding country_name}"  />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you MandrX i will be forever in your debt. When i change the gridview to listView your binding technique worked. Thanks again.

```
<ListView Name="mylistview"  Margin="27,299,41,62">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="0, 20, 0, 0">
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding country_name }" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding country_id}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
```

Comment: Great!! I just built your project to finally see you figured it out already :). Could you please mark my response as answer so I get the points? :P

Btw I suggest you to read this to understand more about databindings: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758320.aspx

Comment: it takes me two days two figure it out. thanks for help.

Comment: No problems, I wish you a lot of fun with Azure and the mobile services! :) Glad to have helped you out.

ps. it's not marked by me, surely a glitch :(

Comment: @MandrX - can you answer that post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32081725/update-table-in-azure-mobile-service?lq=1)